# JAXB Simple XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Please help me to find what's wrong withthis JAXB configuration.I am having this XML to parse.It throws Exception.

**Excpetion :**

```
group : DummyMaster@ae7b77
group : master
group : null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestDummy.main(TestDummy.java:21)
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<master name="master">
    <detail name="detail1">     
    </detail>
    <detail name="detail2">     
    </detail>
</master>
```

**Test :**

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DummyMaster.class);        
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();        
    DummyMaster group = (DummyMaster) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test1.xml"));
    System.out.println("group : "+group);
    System.out.println("group : "+group.getName());
    System.out.println("group : "+group.getDetails());
    System.out.println("group : "+group.getDetails().size());//Line 21
```

**Master :**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="master")
public class DummyMaster {
private String name;
private List<DummyDetail> details;

@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement
public List<DummyDetail> getDetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setDetails(List<DummyDetail> details) {
    this.details = details;
}    
}
```

**Detail :**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="detail")
public class DummyDetail {
private String name;

@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: What is line 21 of TestDummy.java?

Comment: Thanks for reply pls check the updated Question.System.out.println("group : "+group.getDetails().size());//Line 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your DummyMaster class remove @XmlElementWrapper and add @XmlElement(name = "detail")

```
@XmlRootElement(name="master")
public class DummyMaster {

    private String name;
    private List<DummyDetail> details;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    public List<DummyDetail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(List<DummyDetail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a NullPointerException on this line:

```
System.out.println("group : "+group.getDetails().size());
```

Given the lines above it are executed, the only possible explanation is that getDetails() is returning null, meaning when you attempt to call size() on this, you get an NPE.

**Option 1**

This is because your XML does not contain the details wrapper element.

Change your XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<master name="master">
  <details>
    <detail name="detail1">     
    </detail>
    <detail name="detail2">     
    </detail>
  </details>
</master>
```

**Option 2**

In the DummyMaster class, remove the @XmlElementWrapper annotation completely and annotate the getDetails method with @XmlElement(name = "detail").

Then leave the XML as you originally had it.

Comment: can't I have multiple <detail> as I have in my XML mentioned instead of  <detail> with outer tag <details> ?

Comment: You can. Remove the @XmlElementWrapper annotation completely and annotate the getDetails method with @XmlElement(name = "detail"). Then leave the XML as you originally had it.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any way as you required

1. Change only `DummyMaster#getDetails()` **(Without xml element wrapper)**

   ```
   //1. comment out XmlElementWrapper
   //2. name with XmlElement
   //@XmlElementWrapper
   @XmlElement(name="detail")
   public List<DummyDetail> getDetails() {
       return details;
   }
   ```
2. Change on `DummyMaster#getDetails()` and **xml** file compose **(With xml element wrapper)**

   ```
   //method 
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="details")
   @XmlElement(name="detail")
   public List<DummyDetail> getDetails() {
       return details;
   }

   //in xml <details> should wrap child <detail> tag
   <details>
      <detail name="detail1">     
      </detail>
      <detail name="detail2">     
     </detail>
   </details>
   ```